# How to transform categorical data to binary variables on c++?

Tags: c++, unix, awk

I have dataset, where 1 of many variables (2-nd in this example) look like:

Name;school_id

Frad;323

Brad;3245

Drad;6575

Crad;2323

...

Vrad;32443

Here is are 1000 values, I want to make 1000 unique variables (in columns) with binary values

Comment: What do you mean by "binary values"? And you know you can't create variables dynamically in C++? You can store in a vector or some such thing, but it's hard to understand what this question is about What is the actual problem you need to solve? With the input you show what should the output be? And what does `awk` have to do with this? Lastly, what have you tried yourself? What problems do you have with your code?

Comment: Oh, and please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: binary values it's 0 and 1 values. Problem - machine learning model

Comment: Booleans basically.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from the file.

Put it in a `std::vector`.

Use booleans (for true/false) - `bool`

```
std::vector<bool> v;
while(...) // reading data
    v.push_back(true / false);
```